# What is the difference between signature and anomaly based IDS

Tags: security, snort

I was assigned to work on IDS using snort for my internship project. On my study to understand what IDSs is all about i can't seem to clearly understand the different detection techniques ( Signature based and Anomaly Based)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to read the following article, it is short and comprehensible:

https://www.n-able.com/blog/intrusion-detection-system

For short:

Signature-based detection scans for known/similar threats stored in a database.
Anomaly-based detection analyses traffic etc. and finds "anomalies" via algorithmns.